# can I create tables and RLS via any external API or similar?

Tags: supabase

I need to create a custom admin tool, where I create tables and RLS rules outside the Supabase admin dashboard.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out in the documentation for RLS, and in combination with the SQL editor (https://supabase.com/docs/guides/auth/row-level-security)

Wrap this bit in a database function with parameters

```
-- 1. Create table
create table profiles (
  id uuid references auth.users,
  avatar_url text
);

-- 2. Enable RLS
alter table profiles
  enable row level security;

-- 3. Create Policy
create policy "Public profiles are viewable by everyone."
  on profiles for select using (
    true
  );
```

Then call the function with rpc call

Answer (score 1):

You can use any database interaction tool to do this. I am using a nodejs database migration tool in one of my project along with a nodejs postgres client and I'm able to create tables, enable RLS and write policies with this. You can see all the files doing these tasks in my project [here](https://github.com/silentworks/waiting-list/tree/main/migrations).